# Is there a way to handle pop-up informations of HTML form in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to hanlde the pop-up message from HTML form like in pic below? I see that it's not added to DOM via JS after clicking "Zapisz" button.

[image: the element is marked in red[1]]

The HTML code of the form is shown below:

```
<form class="subscription__form">
  <div class="form__email-input">
    <div class="email-input__field">
      <label for="email-ies20" class="boo5QN kuXeGY ZNyelS j5539W Kp7mbJ _6UybFe yOshI6 Vg2G-X QAKJaP">
      </label>
      <input type="email" class="ptY7iQ xm3894 BPoM1b -T32DO j5539W Kp7mbJ JwPapm yOshI6 OJgqNz I7nA9N _7lPid_ pAtLTY ARyIjR _-4XiAI i9UcX3 ySMwvO _1E7gq- KHXx7q" value="" id="email-ies20" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="form__btn jjY3sP ebuQjF i9UcX3 zb5H0w v7Z8MH DH77jT I7nA9N _1VH7VL -lZ0bD lRd-jf fXQLl7 BG_g-B _0DRKyg Ip_fOg Xf3Nnr FDkAoY KHXx7q RkhiHe ajUhiu IB2dWZ ZJBY2X _4U-qxG FfEhSH ee0PKn CoasA5"><span class="_6xw_O3 _85MuCJ HgyryE I7nA9N o4bIWm kuXeGY ZNyelS j5539W Kp7mbJ _6UybFe yOshI6 Vg2G-X"><span class="save-text-container">Zapisz</span></span><svg class="dx-icon ODgekj VPvVHW -QUg1Q XRBrCa Yq7G-r qH0D36 qIhDFL" height="1em" width="1em" focusable="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M12 2a10 10 0 0 0-7 17l1-1a8.5 8.5 0 1 1 6 2.5V22a10 10 0 0 0 0-20z">
    </path>
    </svg>
    <svg class="dx-icon ODgekj qIhDFL" height="1em" width="1em" focusable="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M11.3 19.9l-8.5-6.3 1.5-2 6.4 4.8 8.4-11.7L21 6 11.3 20z">
      </path>
    </svg>
  <svg class="dx-icon ODgekj qIhDFL" height="1em" width="1em" focusable="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M19.6 5.5l-1-1.1-6.6 6.5-6.5-6.5-1.1 1 6.5 6.6-6.5 6.5 1 1.1 6.6-6.5 6.5 6.5 1.1-1-6.5-6.6 6.5-6.5z">
  </path>
  </svg>
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the value using `getattribute('validationMessage')` function.

I created a basic HTML example to show you how extract content of popup  because your HTML code example doesn't work as well to exemplify.

```
from selenium import webdriver

HTML = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" required>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>"""

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%s" % HTML)
input_bt = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
error_msg = input_bt.get_attribute('validationMessage')
print(error_msg)
```

HTML example:

[image: HTML example]

Output console:

```
Please fill out this field.
```

Hope it helps!